# Why is PHP converting '+' to a space even when escaping URL with %2B?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, escaping

I can't seem to pass a '+' symbol to a php file (index.php), even though I'm escaping it properly. To debug the problem I set up a test file (test.php).

I'm using mod_rewrite with the file that doesn't work so that might be related.

Calling /test.php?z=1%2B2 I get:

```
["z"]=> string(3) "1+2"
```

Calling /1%2B2 I get:

```
["z"]=> string(3) "1 2"
```

The .htaccess file redirects the last line to index.php. It contains the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index\.php
RewriteRule ^.* index.php?z=%{REQUEST_URI}

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
php_flag display_errors Off
AddHandler php5-script .php
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b:

> mod_rewrite has to unescape URLs before mapping them, so backreferences will be unescaped at the time they are applied. Using the B flag, non-alphanumeric characters in backreferences will be escaped

Works fine on my test machine with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?z=$1 [B]
```

but haven't tested it with `%{REQUEST_URI}` ...

Comment: This works. It doesn't work with `%{REQUEST_URI}` because that has already been unescaped, and `[B]` only escapes backreferences (`$1`).

Comment: brilliant, thank you. I knew that mod_rewrite was escaping my URI for some reason but I couldn't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the "+" character via url. 
The only way is to replace the character with another before you pass it to the url and replace it afterwards with "+".

Comment: After having the same problem as soulkphp and not finding a workaround, the answer above worked for me.